# How to enforce two objects have the same keys in Typescript using keyof

Tags: typescript

I have an object mapping from names to `id`s which I later want to instantiate. How do I make sure the two objects have the same keys?

For example, discord channels:

```
const channelIds = {
  "cr_category": "551155556021598200",
  "results": "551155093816545200",
};

const channels: ??? = {};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the `?` allows leaving an empty object to initialize fully later if that's what you want.

```
const channelIds = {
  "cr_category": "551155556021598200",
  "results": "551155093816545200",
};

const channels: {
  [name in keyof typeof channelIds]?: discord.TextChannel;
} = {};
```